# Is there a way to efficiently test whether a newly inserted/updated row matches a SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table in my application that periodically has `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements executed against it. I would like to display a view in my application that reflects some query that is run against that table, and keep it continually updated as the table contents change. Since the table could be large, I would like to avoid having to re-run the query each time the table is updated so that I can update the view.

One idea I had was to use SQLite's [Data Change Notification Callbacks](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html) to be notified whenever an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` occurs against the table in question. In my callback, I have the `rowid` of the newly-updated row, and I would like to see whether it matches the query. Assuming I have the query available as a prepared [`sqlite3_stmt`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html), what would be the most efficient way to test whether the row would be matched by the query?

**Aside:** I know that I can't do anything in the callback itself that would affect the state of the database connection, and that's fine. I can defer the actual work of checking the query until later to ensure safety; I'm just trying to determine what the best mechanism for checking the query against the new row contents would be.